# ASP.NET MVC's HttpContext.Request.IsLocal on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-roles

Do you know if calling HttpContext.Request.IsLocal in a Controller's Action on a website running on Azure will return True when calling it via AJAX from a page in the same website?

Thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to solve here?

Comment: I didn't know `IsLocal` existed until I just looked it up - personally I think it sounds like a bad idea most of the time, - if you want to do special stuff while debugging, you can just use a preprocessor `#if DEBUG` - but even with that, I'd be careful to ensure that production code and dev code is functionally identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It will tell you if the request originated from the same machine on which the server is running. Which it probably didn't.

Comment: Hi spender, so how can I tell whether the request is coming from an ajax call in another page of the same application?